# How do I refactor out temporary variables that check a condition?

Tags: python, refactoring

I am currently iterating over data, placing the data within columns based on certain criteria. Please know that I want to avoid Global variables altogether. This is what I am working with:

```
def query_alarm(device):
    """
    Requests data from the device,
    saving each oid and value from the device's
    specified alarm table into a Breadcrumb object.
    """
    column = []
    oid_check = ''
    for (errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, response) in nextCmd(
        SnmpEngine(),
        CommunityData("public"),
        UdpTransportTarget((device.ip_address, device.snmp_port_number)),
        ContextData(),
        ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(manufacturer_alarm_table_oid(device))),
        lexicographicMode=False,
    ):
        if nextcmd_error(errorIndex, errorIndication, errorStatus):
            handle_nextcmd_error()
            continue


        for oid, value in response:
            column_oid = split_column_oid(oid)
            if column_oid != oid_check:
                if len(column) > 0:
                    device.alarm_count = len(column)
                    device.date_checked = timezone.now()
                    device.save()
                column = []
                oid_check = column_oid
            column.append({str(oid): str(value)})
            try:
                Breadcrumb(oid=oid, value=value).save()
            except ValueError as e:
                print(e)
                Breadcrumb(oid=oid, value='*** FIX DateAndTime Value ***').save()


    return True
```

As I refactor this, I'd like to place the `for oid, value in response` iteration and everything under it within its own functions. What is tricking me up, is what to do with the column and oid_check variables that are declared at the beginning of the query_alarm function.

Comment: Try reading this on [passing by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference). I'm not sure if there is a cleaner way though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the variables to the function and return them from the function.

```
def func(oid, value, oid_check, column):
    column_oid = split_column_oid(oid)
    if column_oid != oid_check:
        if len(column) > 0:
            device.alarm_count = len(column)
            device.date_checked = timezone.now()
            device.save()
        column = []
        oid_check = column_oid
    column.append({str(oid): str(value)})
    try:
        Breadcrumb(oid=oid, value=value).save()
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
        Breadcrumb(oid=oid, value='*** FIX DateAndTime Value ***').save()

    return oid_check, column
```

Then call it in a loop like:

```
for oid, value in response:
    oid_check, column = func(oid, value, oid_check, column)
```

Comment: Is `old_check` a typo?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in the variables you need into the function.

You can refactor it this way:

```
def query_alarm(device):
    """
    Requests data from the device,
    saving each oid and value from the device's
    specified alarm table into a Breadcrumb object.
    """
    column = []
    oid_check = ''
    for (errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, response) in nextCmd(
        SnmpEngine(),
        CommunityData("public"),
        UdpTransportTarget((device.ip_address, device.snmp_port_number)),
        ContextData(),
        ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(manufacturer_alarm_table_oid(device))),
        lexicographicMode=False,
    ):
        if nextcmd_error(errorIndex, errorIndication, errorStatus):
            handle_nextcmd_error()
            continue   

        column, oid_check = func1(response, column, oid_check)

    return True

def func1( response, column, oid_check ):
    for oid, value in response:
        column_oid = split_column_oid(oid)
        if column_oid != oid_check:
            if len(column) > 0:
                device.alarm_count = len(column)
                device.date_checked = timezone.now()
                device.save()
            column = []
            oid_check = column_oid
        column.append({str(oid): str(value)})
        try:
            Breadcrumb(oid=oid, value=value).save()
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
            Breadcrumb(oid=oid, value='*** FIX DateAndTime Value ***').save()
    return column, oid_check
```

Comment: Yes, but address the indentation. The best way is to copy and paste from your editor, then highlight the code and press ctrl-k

Comment: This won't work. The assignment to `oid_check` in `func1` doesn't update the argument that's passed to the next iteration.

Comment: @Barmar you can pass the data back from func_1 to the main function. I've updated the code.

Comment: Fix your indentation at the bottom

Comment: @Barmar Fixed :)